# how to test for passwords entries of a 7zip file using a python script?

Tags: python, 7zip

I would like to write a python script to test passwords for a 7zip file, is there a function that allow to write in the password field of the 7zip file ?

Thanks

Comment: Download the command-line version of 7zip and invoke its behavior using `subprocess.check_output`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there is a particular function that might help you but what I usually do is that just run terminal commands from python (I use a Linux system).

```
import os
import subprocess

subprocess.call (["7z", "x", "test.7z", "-ppasswd"])
```

In the above example test is the name of your file and passwd is the password that you need for decompression.